# Hot Towel: Why is Durandal and Require in the App folder rather than the Script folder?

Tags: requirejs, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

This is coming from the idea of 3rd party libraries being in Script to discourage developers from customizing them.  It would encourage them to write extensions to make it easier to take in a new version of either library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make a good point about other developers mistaking the durandal libraries for customizable files.

But, you are not required to keep durandal anywhere.  The folder structure can be whatever your heart desires.  Because durandal does not impose any folder structure.. it only has a recommeneded default setup.  There are benifits to following its pattern.

By keeping durandal as part of your application root folder. It keeps all your amd javascript files together in one root folder. This way when you run the durandal [optimizer](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/) it can scan every subfolder to compress/minify/uglify all your html/css/js  into 1 file. This is a nice benifit because its a 1 click build of your entire application.

Also, its a nice seperation because its a good idea to keep your 3rd party non-amd JavaScript libraries in a separate folder structure this way if you use a [bundler](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) to compress all your third party libraries into a separate file.  The browser can cache your application separate from the third-party libraries.  Because the third-party libraries don't change very often, whereas your application will probably be changing frequently.

But durandal's conventions are all completely configurable and you can put durandal in any location you like.

Comment: I accept your answer, and now understand the Durandal convention.  However I would assume there are parts of Durandal that are core to its function.  If you have a multi-SPA situation you would want all the SPAs to share/cache Durandal's core code.  My perspective is from ExtJs, in which everything in your app folder is custom to your app.  Everything that could be shared by other apps was in the script folder or a CDN.  The stuff in script was never edited directly - only indirectly through extension files.  The convention made it very clear what should and should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is a convention that Durandal has decided to use to help keep your customer client code organized in an App folder and away from the 3rd party scripts folder, which gets pretty messy pretty quickly. It does put require.js in the App folder because of the way it relies on require.js and its AMD pattern. require.js is used to help locate all modules and load them as needed (in your App folder).

Is there something specific that you need that this is preventing?